# Flutter on screen keyboard key press detection call back

Tags: flutter

What i'm initially trying to achieve is a haptics vibration from my own plugin package when ever a key is pressed on the on screen keyboard.
Maybe i'm going the wrong way about it.

Ive turned on iOS system haptics but the on screen keyboard in flutter doesn't vibrate on key press with that on.

I have an EditableText that brings up the keyboard with a focusNode in it.
In the creation of that focus node ive tried the following with no luckw:

```
 _focusNode = FocusNode(
         onKey: (node, event) {
           HapticsPlugin().click();
           print("hello?");
           return KeyEventResult.handled;
         },
        );
```

I've also tried this with no luck, it only detects hardware keyboard presses:

```
widget.focusNode.addListener(() {
      print("pressed?");
    });
```

I've also tried this with no luck, and again it only detects hardware keyboard presses:

```
 window.onKeyData = (final keyData) {
      print("window.onKeyData");
      return false;
    };
```

Ive tried wrapping the EditableText in a RawKeyboardListener but when using the same focus node for each widget you get the following error:

```
Tried to make a child into a parent of itself.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart':
focus_manager.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 987 pos 12: 'child != this'
```

And using separate nodes, well It doesn't work because I need to detects what's pressed inside the EditableText.
The closest thing is the onChanged in EditableText but that event doesn't fire off when you tap your finger down, its when you lift up and the character is entered.

And also the RawKeyboardListener again seem to only listen to hardware key presses and not on screen key presses.

And just to make sure, the onTap inside EditableText obviously only detects a general tap on the textfield of the EditableText and not the system on screen keyboard taps.

Is there anyway I can have an EditableText in focus with the on screen keyboard up and detect with a callback anytime a key is pressed on that on screen keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I've found some what of a solution that does behave how I want but it doesn't feel like the way I should be doing it.

Adding a listener to the TextEditingController

```
 _numberFieldCont.addListener(() {
      IwHapticsPlugin().click();
      print("Pressed?");
    });
```

I'd still love to hear if there's a more proper way of achieving this, if there is one out there.